# Mongoosejs find with select returns unwanted array field

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema:

```
var schema =  mongoose.Schema({
        name: 'string',
        title: 'string'
        tracks: [trackSchema],
    });
```

When I try to select records and limit selected fields:

```
Model.find({}).select('name').exec(cb)
```

the result includes _id, name AND tracks fields (it does not include "title"). But why does it include tracks??

I can exclude it only doing:

```
Model.find({}).select('-tracks').exec(cb)
```

So I wonder what is going on and how I can select only "name" filed

Mongoose 3.8.6

Comment: And you're not using `select: true` in your schema?

Comment: Yes, you are right, inside my trackSchema. Thank you. You may post the answer I will check it as correct.

Comment: Well, I'm interested now: because you have a `select : true` in `trackSchema`, it was added to the results of a query on another model (`Model`)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks to @robertklep

The problem was that trackSchema for one of its fields contained {select: true}

```
var trackSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   prop: {type: {....}, select: true}
});
```